# How to programmatically quit AirPlay mode for HTML5 <video>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, airplay

I am working on a webpage with multiple  components with AirPlay enabled. How do I quit a video in AirPlay when user clicks another video. I don't want to have two videos playing at the same time or switch the other video into AirPlay.